# ASP.NET MVC 2 Calling html helper inside if conditional statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view

I'm having a problem getting the syntax correct.  The html helper returns true or false.

```
<% if (<%= Html.SecurityTrim("Admin")%>) { %>  
            <span>Only for accounting</span> 
    <% } %>
```

What do I need to change to get this to compile correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that `Html.SecurityTrim()` returns `bool`,

```
<% if ( Html.SecurityTrim("Admin") ) { %>  
    <span>Only for accounting</span> 
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `Html.SecurityTrim()` returns a bool.

In this case, then no need to escape out of code, just use it as your condition to test.

```
<% if (Html.SecurityTrim("Admin")) { %>  
            <span>Only for accounting</span>   
  <% } %>
```